# Optimise glide Loading 1000+ images thumbnails, for android Image gallery

Tags: android, user-interface, gallery, android-glide

Hi There:) I am trying to create Image Gallery in Android, I am trying to load Thumbnails from HD images(more than 1000) from local device.

```
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(MyPhotoList.get(position).getPath()))).override(110,110)/*.thumbnail(0.1f)*/
            .placeholder(R.color.colorAccent).into(holder.image);
```

But on scroll, RecycleView  stucks and load image after few sec.(CPU: 70-80%, 180 MB, It consumes.)
(Test Device config. Deca-core 2.3 GHz, 4 Gb RAM).

Could you please suggest me, how to make smooth scrolling for image gallery.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is normal behavior. On every another app launch (after the first one) glide will load those photos from its cache so it will be much smoothier.

To explain this just calculate, the phone needs to load e.g 20 photos those size together is about ~200/300 MB. Now take device's flash memory read speed. Most of devices may have about speed rate up to ~120 mb/s, so it means it may load those photos in few seconds.

Take a quick try with stock Gallery app on your phone. Open this and swipe down and see images and videos loading and compare with your app speed. Then you will know how big is difference againist those apps if any.

Comment: Tried other applications on my phone, they are working well